# Python SQLite: Inserting 0 integer becomes NULL in database

Tags: python, sql, python-2.7, sqlite

I have some Python code that inserts integer values to a database, as below:

```
if value: #if it's not None
    self._conn.execute(
    '''UPDATE table_name SET value_holder = ? WHERE
        key_one = ? AND key_two = ? and key_three = ?''',
        [value, key_one, key_two, key_three])
```

If I run that query, table will contain empty fields, or NULL fields whenever value is 0. If I change the query setup to below, however, the fields will contain 0 instead of NULL.

```
if value==0:
    self._conn.execute(
    '''UPDATE table_name SET value_holder = ? WHERE
        key_one = ? AND key_two = ? and key_three = ?''',
        [0, key_one, key_two, key_three])

elif value: #if it's not None
    self._conn.execute(
    '''UPDATE table_name SET value_holder = ? WHERE
        key_one = ? AND key_two = ? and key_three = ?''',
        [value, key_one, key_two, key_three])
```

How is it possible that inserting 0 vs inserting value (when value==0) results in different values in the database?

SQLite version 3.3.6.

Comment: `if value` will not be true when `value` is 0.

Comment: `if value: #if it's not None`. That's not how you check for `None`. `if value is not None` is how you do it. https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#truth-value-testing

Comment: Oh... I didn't realize that Python sees 0 as None in that regard. That cleared it up, thanks for the input.

Comment: It doesn't see 0 as `None`, but rather 0 evaluates to `False`

Comment: Nathaniel, yes, you are correct. Miswording on my part.

Comment: interjay, please post your comment as an answer so that I can accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As user interjay answered: 
"if value will not be true when value is 0."

In my case, value was evaluated to false and the default null value was left unchanged in the database.

Supporting documentation posted by user netcoder:
https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#truth-value-testing